# Prometheus/Grafana plot wait time percentiles for jobs

Tags: grafana, prometheus, job-scheduling

I have a job scheduling engine which can run jobs on various machines. I  have a queue of pending jobs coming in as a stream (usually at least 10s of thousands of jobs waiting for execution). I have an algorithm to execute jobs on different machines.

One of the core metrics to track is how long after a job gets requested does it get scheduled for execution (usually it is less than 5 minutes, but can be up to 1 hour due to various reasons).

Is there a way to plot the percentiles of how long the current unassigned jobs have been in there for using Prometheus + Grafana (or mix of prometheus and other solutions like Redis)? I want to know what is Median waiting time, 95 and 99 percentiles of waiting times for the jobs.

The issue is until the job gets scheduled for execution there is no event generated and longer we wait the higher bucket the job will move into. Furthermore, since the job could take very different times to get scheduled (not each job is the same), simply relying on how long past few jobs took to get scheduled is wrong.

One simple way would to iterate over all pending jobs and compute the percentiles continuously, but that would be very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The Prometheus histogram implementations assume a fixed set of buckets (e.g. less than 1 second, less than 2 seconds, less than 5 seconds etc.) which may only be incremented (together with all buckets above them).

In your case, you have 2 options:

1. Record the duration each job has been queued for in the histogram. The problems with this approach are that (a) you would have to keep "moving" every job up the histogram as time goes on; and (b) you can't remove a job from the histogram once it is processed (because of the monotonicity requirement).
2. Record the time when each job was added into a histogram (e.g. records added before 1 minute past the hour, records added before 2 minutes past the hour etc.). The problem here is that your histogram is not static in size and will grow indefinitely (assuming your Prometheus client allowed it in the first place).

You are thus left with a couple of alternatives:

1. Iterate over your queue and create a fresh histogram (or directly the percentiles you're interested in) every time you're scraped by Prometheus. Tens of thousands of jobs to iterate over doesn't sound all that bad, it should take milliseconds to do. You could even replace the data structure you use for your queue with e.g. a binary search tree, which should make it real easy to figure out the exact percentiles you are interested in, in logarithmic time.
2. Give up on recording queuing times for pending jobs and only do it for processed jobs. Every time a job is processed, you increment a histogram. It doesn't get simpler than that.